# XCode Custom Keyboard's additional settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard

I am trying to figure out how to create additional settings inside of the Settings app on iOS.  Right now I am using the Settings.bundle, and it is putting the settings underneath the original keyboard settings.  But from what I have seen from other custom keyboards,  you can access additional settings by going to Settings->General->Keyboard->Keyboards->Your Keyboard Name->Additional Settings.

Right now I can get to as far as Your Keyboard Name, I have no idea what to implement to be able to make the Additional Settings.

Normally I would google this, but I do not even know what to look for to find this,  and all my searches lead me to Settings.bundle.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Also  I am doing this in swift, but I do not need the answer in swift if it is not known, I can figure it out myself after I get that nudge.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,  I have found the answer.  You need to go into the info plist of the extension,  expand nsextension, expand nsextensionattributes, and inside that,  set requestopenaccess to yes,  that will expand the keyboards settings to allow you to set open access or not